# How to check for the route using react?

Tags: reactjs

i want to add spacing when the user is in page "/items/:itemId" using react.

below is my snippet,

```
function child () {
    return (
        <popupContext.Provider value={context}>
            {children}
            {(condition1 || condition2) && (
                <Popup onHide={on_hide} />
            )}
        </popupContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

So in the above snippet, if condition1 or condition2 is true and in any page it renders Popup component.

**what i want to do?**

now when user is in page "/items/:itemId" and condition1 or condition2 is true it should render Popup component along with  Spacing componet like below

something like below

```
<Route
    path="/items/:itemId"
    render={routeProps => (
        <Popup onHide={on_hide}/>
        <Spacing dir="x" amount={16} />
    )}
/>
```

So basically when user is in path "/items/:itemId" and condition1 or condition2, i want to render popup and spacing components.

when in page other than this and condition1 or condition2 i want to render only popup component.

how do i rewrite above snippet such that when user is in any page other than "/items/:itemId" it should render only Popup component and when in page "items/:itemId" should render Popup with spacing component

how can i fix this code. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `<React.Fragment /> and with conditional rendering`:

```
<Route
    path="/items/:itemId"
    render={routeProps => (condition1 || condition2) ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Popup onHide={on_hide}/>
          <Spacing dir="x" amount={16} />
        </React.Fragment>
    ) : null}
/>
```

Comment: so this will check  in route /items/:itemId and condition1 or condition2 will render popup with spacing. if not condition1 or condition2 renders null in items/:itemId page...?

Comment: this doesnt render the popup with spacing

Comment: If you can provide a working code example, it becomes easier to identify your problem.

Comment: i think there is a problem in the way i am passing the routeprops to Popup component. how should the routeprops be used in the Popup componets

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)